# C - Why am I allowed to do this?

Tags: c, pointers

```
int b[2], *ptr;
b[0] = 5;
b[1] = 7;

ptr = &b[0];
*ptr++ = 66;

printf("%d", *ptr);
```

Why am I allowed to do the `*ptr++ = 66` line even though the `= 66` bit seems to do nothing? When I print `*ptr` it's 7. Can anyone explain why? Shouldn't the compiler complain about the `= 66` bit not having an effect?

Isn't `*ptr++ = 66` basically equivalent to `7 = 66`?

Comment: `ptr = &b[0];` is redundant; you can use `ptr=buf` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's happening is this:

1. `b[0]` is assigned a value of `66` because you're deferencing `ptr`, i.e. you're doing `*ptr`, then performing the assignment
2. The pointer itself is incremented, i.e. `&b[0]++`, which becomes `&b[1]`
3. `ptr` is now pointing to `b[1]`, which is `7`

To put it another way: the incrementation and the assignment are performed on two totally different things. And since it's a postfix increment, the pointer is incremented *after* its original address receives a new value.

Comment: I understand what the *ptr++ bit of code does, but why am I able to assign that expression to a number?

Comment: @Sam: You're dereferencing `ptr` and assigning 66 to whatever value it corresponds to, but you're incrementing the pointer itself.

Comment: Just for giggles: try `*(++ptr)=99;`

Answer (score 2):

You're incrementing the pointer. It points to b[1] after that. The value of b[0] is probably 66.

Comment: Yep, I understand that but why does the compiler let me assign *ptr++ to a number even though it has no effect?

Comment: 5? But the compiler won't let me type 5++ = 7;

Answer (score 1):

The `ptr++` is called *post increment*, this mean that you *first* use the old value of `ptr` (overwriting the `5`), then increment `ptr`.

Comment: Thank you! So the equivalent code is basically *ptr = 66; *ptr++;? This makes sense to me.

Comment: Actually that doesn't make sense cause then *ptr would be 67.

Comment: It's equivalent of `*ptr = 66; ptr++`. This mean that you increment the *pointer*, not what it points to.

Answer (score 1):

You increment the pointer. If you want to increment the value of the pointer use `(*ptr)++`.

See this [precedence table](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm)